# SQL- make all rows show a column value if one of the rows has it

Tags: sql, foxpro

I have an SQL statement for a PICK sheet that returns the header/detail records for an order.
One of the fields in the SQL is basically a field to say if there are dangerous goods. If a single product on the order has a code against it, then the report should display that its hazardous.

The problem I am having is that in the SQL results, because I am putting the code on the report in the header section (and not the detail section), it is looking for the code only on the first row.

Is there a way through SQL to basically say "if one of these rows has this code, make all of these rows have this code"? I'm guessing a subselect would work here... the problem is, is that I am using a legacy system built on FoxPro and FoxPro SQL is terrible!

EDIT: just checked and I am running VFP8, subqueries in the SELECT statement were added in FVP9 :(

Comment: If I am reading your problem correctly, the header contains the dangerous goods field and if the header contains a valid value for dangerous goods, then all of the details records needs to contain that field. If this is the case, have you tried a `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: Hi. No, the detail records contain the dangerous goods code. If one field has a dangerous goods code, I need all fields to have the code so that the report designer will pick up this field (as in the report, the field is on the header, and the header looks at the last row of the returned SQL). I almost need to use an aggregate (such as a MAX) on the dangerous goods column...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Header.HeaderId, Header.HeaderDescription, 
    Detail.DetailId, Detail.DetailDescription, Detail.Dangerous, 
    Danger.DangerousItems
FROM Header
INNER JOIN Detail ON Header.HeaderId = Detail.HeaderId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT HeaderId, COUNT(*) AS DangerousItems FROM Detail WHERE Dangerous = 1 GROUP BY HeaderId) Danger ON Header.HeaderId = Danger.HeaderId
```

If `Danger.DangerousItems` > 0 then something is dangerous. If it is Null then nothing is dangerous.

If you can't do nested queries, then you should be able to create a view-like object (called a [query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979396%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in VFP8) for the nested select:

```
SELECT HeaderId, COUNT(*) AS DangerousItems FROM Detail WHERE Dangerous = 1 GROUP BY HeaderId
```

and then can you left join on that?

Comment: VFP8 doesn't support derived tables- subqueries in the FROM clause :(

Comment: Okay, but how about creating a query on the nested select and joining on that, as suggested?

Comment: I will have to look into that. I don't really have access to be adding views to the database- well, that is what you are proposing isn't it? Create a view (I come from Oracle) and join onto that as if its a table?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. Another thing to try would be to create a function which runs the nested query and returns whether something is dangerous and use that to populate the report.

Comment: The function idea sounds good.. although I have no idea where to begin creating the function with FoxPro. Once again, I'm an Oracle man and FoxPro is just something completely different!

Answer (score 0):

In VFP 8 and earlier, your best bet is to use three queries in a row:

SELECT Header.HeaderId, Header.HeaderDescription, 
    Detail.DetailId, Detail.DetailDescription, Detail.Dangerous, 
    Danger.DangerousItems
FROM Header
INNER JOIN Detail ON Header.HeaderId = Detail.HeaderId
INTO CURSOR csrDetail

SELECT HeaderId, COUNT(*) AS DangerousItems 
   FROM Detail 
   WHERE Dangerous 
   GROUP BY HeaderId
   INTO CURSOR csrDanger

SELECT csrDetail.*, csrDanger.DangerousItems 
  FROM csrDetail.HeaderID = csrDanger.HeaderID 
  INTO CURSOR csrResult

Comment: Unfortunately this is not going to work either. The software basically builds your query for you.. as in it has a text box for the SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUPBY, HAVING, INTO and ORDERBY clause. It builds the SQL from these so I don't see how I will be able to put in multiple queries.